# Making physics bodies responsive to fields but not to other physics bodies

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

In my game I have a body that flies across the screen, and is supposed to be affected by a radial gravity field that I have created. To do this, I needed to turn the

```
body.dynamic = true
```

But this results in the body colliding with other objects (with physics bodies) that are on the screen, when I just want it to be affected by the field and not by these objects. If I turn the

```
body.dynamic = false
```

then it doesn't get affected by the field. 
What should I do to make the body stay on its path?

**EDIT** This is my code for the main body that flies across the screen, after a node has already been created

```
 body.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: rectangle)
    body.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    body.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.body
    body.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.otherBody
    body.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    body.physicsBody?.fieldBitMask = PhysicsCategory.shield
    body.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
```

The image shows the 2 possible ways I want the body to avoid colliding with the object. Either it can pass through it, or it can pass around it and return to the earlier path. How do I do that?

[image: The two possible paths]

Comment: You should add a code which shows how you create SKFieldNode and how you set its categoryBitMask etc. Also, you should add this info about other relevant bodies. In the meanwhile you could peek at the docs to check if is everything set up correctly in your code : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html

Comment: Thanks, but everything else is set up properly. I checked the docs

Comment: As Whirlwind said you should show as some code.

Comment: Ok done that @Darvydyas. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set

```
body.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
```

`collisionBitMask` - A mask that defines which categories of physics bodies can collide with this physics body. **IF the value is not set your `PhysicsBody` collides with every other `PhysicsBodies`, If value is set to 0 your `PhysicsBody` do not collide with other `PhysicsBodies`**

I you set `collisionBitMask = 0` your `body` node will go through all other nodes, if you whant it to collide you need to set node `physicsBody?.collisionBitMask` (for example if you whant your node to collide only with ball and wall `physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = kCategoryWall | kCategoryBall`)

I hope it was helpfull

Comment: Thank you! That worked. It passes through. But if I want it to go around and then return to its original path what should I do? @Darvydas

Comment: @Dieblitzen its a harder question. For doing that you need to work with your node physicBody (i never tried it but i know a little) instead of using SKAction.move... you should use applyImpulse and etc.

Comment: @Dieblitzen - you could make every other sprite collide with your body by setting the necessary bits in their collisionBitMak (do a logical OR with PhysicsCategory.body) . Then the body would proceed in a straight line but everything else would bounce off it. If you want it to go around anything in it's path then that's trickier.